# Adding images in raw PDF

Tags: image, pdf, postscript

I am trying to make pdf's manually. I got the basics but the one thing I cannot figure out is images.

The thing I am trying right now, as a start, is adding a simple image in the form of binary code. The binary code has a length of 9 and should be able to represent a black and white image of 3x3. The code being: 111000111 (this should just be a black horizontal line through the middle). Ofcourse this is over simplified, not compressed and not usable for more complex images but I am desperate and just want to display SOMETHING :).

Hope someone can help and teach me more about this topic.

my new pdf (after johnwhitington comment except for point b)

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj
  << 

     /Pages 2 0 R
     /Type /Catalog  >>
endobj

2 0 obj
  << 

     /Type /Pages
     /Count 1
     /Kids [3 0 R]  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
  << 

    /Type /Page
    /Parent 2 0 R  
    /Contents [4 0 R]
    /MediaBox [500 500]

    /Resources 
    <<
      /XObject 
      <<
        /Im1 5 0 R
      >>
    >>
  >>
endobj


4 0 obj 
  <<

  >>
    stream
      q
        1 0 0 1 100 100 cm
        /Im1 Do
      Q
    endstream
endobj


5 0 obj 
  <<
    /Type /XObject
    /Subtype /Image
    /Height 3
    /Width 3
    /BitsPerComponent 1
    /Length 9
    /ColorSpace /DeviceGray
  >>
    stream111000111endstream
endobj


trailer
  << /Root 1 0 R
   /Size 7
  >>
%%EOF
```

my old PDF:

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj
  << 

     /Pages 2 0 R
     /Type /Catalog  >>
endobj

2 0 obj
  << 

     /Type /Pages
     /Count 1
     /Kids [3 0 R]  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
  << 

    /Type /Page
    /Parent 2 0 R  
    /Contents [4 0 R]

    /Resources 
    <<
      /ProcSet [/PDF /ImageB]    
      /XObject 
      <<
        /Im1 5 0 R
      >>
    >>
  >>
endobj


4 0 obj 
  <<

  >>
    stream
      q
        1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
        /Im1 DO
      Q
    endstream
endobj


5 0 obj 
  <<
    /Type /XObject
    /Subtype /Image
    /Height 3
    /Width 3
    /BitsPerComponent 1
    /Length 9
    /ColorSpace /DeviceGray
  >>
    stream111000111endstream
endobj


trailer
  << /Root 1 0 R
   /Size 7
  >>
%%EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@johnwhitington has covered the basic image programming in a PDF

The image is placed and scaled **usually** using four lines of code in a `q` block in the pages contents such as this working single line:-

```
q 192 0 0 192 100 100 cm /Img0 Do Q
```

192 is the dx and dy, 0 is the "skew" 100 is the x y, Img0 is the image number and `Do` is the stacked write code. None of this describes what real size `Img0` is

To see a jpeg insertion using a hybrid text approach (after the text is prepared) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75710613/10802527

So you  need to inject the image pixels using any method that works in the editor, for RGB images JPG import is simplest HOWEVER JPG is not an ideal format for PDF as its pure binary and most text files cannot use pure binary inputs. So for MP4 video and JPEG images they need to be converted into a text safe format such as textual HeX `00 01 02 03` etc thus all 256 ANSI codes can be written into an ANSI editor, such as NotePad.

In other byte words 1 bit black is `00` and white is `FF` for RGB that's `FFFFFF` and `000000`

Right, so how to write that pixel is like this set a pointer to an object in the page resources perhaps an entry like `<</XObject <</Img0 6 0 R>>>>` the

`6 0 obj` needs declarations such as number of pixels and colors and encoding type.

```
6 0 obj <</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/ColorSpace/Device...
```

in your example we can see

```
16 0 obj 
  <<
    /Type /XObject
    /Subtype /Image
    /Height 3
    /Width 3
    /BitsPerComponent 1
    /Length 9
    /ColorSpace /DeviceGray
  >>
stream
 ­ 
endstream
```

note that will without any visible object between stream `start` and `endstream` produce this odd image WHY ! that looks like it should be

`001101101`

[image]

the answer is because its what's really there as binary stream which is not visible in an ANSI editor like notepad.

the characters are binary `20 AD A0` where 20 is a blank whitespace and AD is
binary `101 01101` and `\n` = `A0`

so those bytes look like

```
00100000
10101101
10100000
```

lets test that by widen to 6 bits and as expected we now get this

[image]

So the core issue is that in a text format the bits are taken as literal  NOT visible 01's which cannot be convenient for handling imagery. At this level what we need is to start use an encoding such as ASCII HeX (/ASCIIHexDecode)

### Answer

So a PDF is a Bitstream as a ByteStream and you want `111000111`
that will be

```
111
000
111
```

thus its

```
11100000
00000000
11100000
```

easy use this or similar

```
stream
àà
endstream
```

where there is an invisible black character between the two `à` 's
result will be pixel perfect, but shows that black 00000000 characters are not easy to write in ANSI text they ideally need HEX coding one trick for RGB is use a white space for black as [space] = \x20 = thus as dark as a "safe" ANSI text character can be in its bytes format. so blackish and white as 8 bits would be `ÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿ`

[image]

Hence for a similar, BUT black**ish** result as above we could use

```
    /Height 3
    /Width 3
    /BitsPerComponent 8
    /Length 27
    /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
  >>
stream
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
endstream
endobj
```

Answer (score 1):

A few hints:

a) You need Do not DO.

b) If it's one bit per component, and nine pixels, there will be two bytes (nine bits), not nine bytes in the image. '1' and '0' are 8-bit characters, not bits.

c) You don't need ProcSet these days.

d) To see your image on the screen, you'll want something like 1 0 0 1 100 100 cm to scale it up so it's visible.

e) Your page needs a /MediaBox

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your comment. I have implementend a, c, d and e. 
So how would I add the binary stream in the document? I am writing this with VSCode but want to eventually create a Java program which writes the pdf. Is it possible to insert the binary stream into the document using VSCode.
I am not used working with binary.

Comment: To avoid having to deal with binary, look into the ASCIIHexDecode filter for PDF streams.

Comment: And you want [0 0 500 500] for that MediaBox.